# How to execute an method in Fragment B from a Fragment A

Tags: android, view, fragment

I am a newbie in developing Android, and now I am getting a problem when calling method between Fragments. Let me describe and I hope everyone can help me resolve it.

Fragment A

```
public class A extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {
   .........
   .........
   .........
   public void showContent(int pSelectedIndex, int pSelectedSubIndex) {
    // Create fragment and give it an argument specifying the article it
    RelativeLayout thisTopLayout = (RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.directoryTopRelativeLayout);
    thisTopLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
    RelativeLayout thisBodyLayout = (RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.directoryBodyRelativeLayout);
    thisBodyLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    if (pSelectedIndex == 1) {
        BusinessView thisItem = new BusinessView();
        transaction.replace(R.id.directoryLayout, thisItem);
        thisItem.DetectContentType(pSelectedSubIndex, this.getActivity());
    }
      }
}
```

Fragment B

```
public class B extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void DetectContentType(int selectedType, Activity pActivity){
    if (selectedType != 1) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(pActivity)
                .create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("EXAMPLE");
        alertDialog
                .setMessage("SHOW MESSAGE");
        alertDialog.setButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
                    final int which) {
                // here you can add functions
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setButton2("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
                    final int which) {
                // here you can add functions
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    } else {
        showContent(selectedType);
    }
}

public void showContent(int pSelectedIndex) {
    // Create fragment and give it an argument specifying the article it
    RelativeLayout thisTopLayout = (RelativeLayout) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.businessTopRelativeLayout);
    thisTopLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
    RelativeLayout thisBodyLayout = (RelativeLayout) this.getActivity()
            .findViewById(R.id.businessBodyRelativeLayout);
    thisBodyLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    BusinessItemView thisItem = new BusinessItemView(pSelectedIndex);
    transaction.replace(R.id.businessLayout, thisItem);
    // Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit();
}
}
```

It is my classes, I want to execute method "showContent" in fragment B when I am in Fragment A, but I can just show Alert, but the method "showContent" always get crashed error.

Please give me your idea for this case.
Thanks so much.

Comment: Add your logcat output.

Answer (score 2):

In fragment A you will want to change your method calls around slightly;

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction();
if (pSelectedIndex == 1) {
    BusinessView thisItem = new BusinessView();
    transaction.replace(R.id.directoryLayout, thisItem);
    transaction.commit();
    thisItem.DetectContentType(pSelectedSubIndex, this.getActivity());
}
```

Your DetectContentType method on fragment B cannot do anything with AlertDialogs until the fragment has been attached through a transaction, by calling commit.

Also in your specific case despite supplying the activity to use for the AlertDialog builder, which should be fine for your case, although un-required if committing the transaction you are passing in `pSelectedSubIndex`, not knowing the value of that from your example you might be hitting `showContent()` on fragment B which will definitely fail as you can't attach views until you start the Fragment lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marcus. It is very helpful for me.
But unfortunately, I still can not run even though I set "commit" to finish that transaction.